# How to negate a boolean value in Razor

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

I have the following syntax in Razor:

```
<button disabled="@IsEnabled">
```

My question is simply, how can I negate this value in the HTML?  I've tried doing things like:

```
<button disabled="@!IsEnabled">

<button disabled="!@IsEnabled">

<button disabled="@(() => IsEnabled)">
```

And various usage of brackets to try to pursuade Razor to take the not (!) operator as a valid part of the syntax.  I was under the impression that anything after the @ symbol was valid C# - is this not the case; and, without negating the method itself in C#, is there a way to change the value in the Razor syntax?

Comment: `disabled` is a property not a attribute, your using it wrong. The presence of `disabled` is enough to make something disabled, `disabled="false"` is incorrect usage, though it does work on most browsers

Comment: Use `@()` instead of `@` (`@(!IsEnabled)`)

Comment: @Liam if this is the wrong way - and I accept what you're saying about disabled, then is there a way to control whether or not the control is enabled in the "right" way?

Comment: @Ammar that doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: `<button @(IsEnabled ? "" : "disabled=\"disabled\"")>`

Comment: @VDWWD that doesn't seem to be valid Razor syntax

Comment: It is in cshtml. But maybe you need the Model? `<button @(Model.IsEnabled ? "" : "disabled=\"disabled\"")>`?

Comment: This worked:  `<button disabled="@(!IsDisabled)">`